# Impossible to create a device group from android device

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Since few days my app is not able anymore to create a device group from my android app. According to Firebase docs we should be able to manage device groups from server or client side. I didn't change my app from few years! So I guess something is changed without any reference in the docs. Currently my app does:

```
 JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
 data.put("operation", "add");
 data.put("notification_key_name", notificationKeyName);
 data.put("registration_ids", new
 JSONArray(Collections.singletonList(registrationId)));
 data.put("id_token", idToken);
 RequestBody body = RequestBody.create(MEDIA_TYPE_JSON, data.toString());
 Request oreq = new
 Request.Builder().url("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/googlenotification")
  .addHeader("project_id", projectId)
  .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
  .addHeader("Accept", "application/json")
  .post(body)
  .build();
```

where the notification key name is the user email of Google account the token is retrieved using

```
String idToken = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(this, account, scope);
```

and the registration id is retrieved using

```
FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().getToken()
```

When the app now sends the request the result is "sender denied" but as I said I didn't change anything. In the Firebase docs however I can't find anymore any reference to the endpoint `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/googlenotification` so is it changed anything?
I tracked the web page with firebase doc and I saw that the section relative to the client android app management of device groups has been removed one year ago, on 18th March 2020.

Comment: Based on this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#creating_a_device_group i found that they change the endpoint to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/notification and they also added in header: Authorization:key=API_KEY.

Comment: Actually from that link they still say you can manage the groups from Android client app but they don't say how anymore. The section you are talk about is the server section indeed in the examples the server key is used. They changed the web page on 18th March 2020 but it's not clear why.

Comment: Yes you are right they removed that section.

Comment: I have tested this request with the new url: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/notification with the Authorization:key=API_KEY (Server Key) in header according to Server section guidelines (Managing device groups on the app server) https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group#creating_a_device_group and it works, the response is the notification_key. I didn't find anything else related with the Client App.

Comment: Yes, I know, I tried too but it's not what I want. I can't simply add the server key in the android app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reply to myself: Firebase support finally replied saying that the client support has been removed without any advice. No solution to this problem. Personal note: don't use anymore Firebase products.